# How to insert multiple rows from xml document to sql server using XmlReader

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlreader

Of course, I googled my problem : "visual basic xml to sql how to insert many rows XmlReader". I even changed 'many' to 'multiple'.

So far, I was able to add only the **first** entry into my database.
I was happy to be able to use XmlReader, since I heard it's quite efficient.
I was happy as well to be able to use parameters, since I can't concatenate properly anyway (and yes, I like to code elegantly - I do not talk about my clothes here).

My VB.Net code:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1
Private Sub ButtonOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonOK.Click        
    Dim xmlFile As String           
    Dim connectionString As String  
    Dim connection As SqlConnection 
    Dim command As SqlCommand       
    Dim ds As New DataSet           
    Dim reader As XmlReader         
    Dim sqlStatement As String      

    'Tag names inside xml document, will have to be inserted into table
    Dim company As Integer
    Dim name As String
    Dim streetaddress As String
    Dim city As String        
    Dim status As Char

    connectionString = "this connection string works"
    xmlFile = "MyXMLFile.xml"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, New XmlReaderSettings())
    ds.ReadXml(reader)

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(xmlFile)
    Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes(".//siteelement/site")
    For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            company = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))                
            name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
            streetaddress = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)                
            city = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3)                
            status = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4)

            sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SITE] ([COMPANY], [NAME], [STREETADDRESS], [CITY], [STATUS])" &
            "VALUES (@COMPANY, @NAME, @STREETADDRESS, @CITY, @STATUS)"
            command = New SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY", company)                
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", name)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STREETADDRESS", streetaddress)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITY", city)                
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", status)
            Try
                connection.Open()
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show(rowsAffected & " entries were inserted into Site table")
                'Release the resources
                command.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
            'Execute the sql statement against the connection
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Next
    connection.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

What my xml file look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<siteelement>
<site>
  <company>1000</company>   
  <name>STORE #2336</name>
  <streetAddress>123 London Calling</streetAddress> 
  <city>London</city>   
  <status>I</status>
</site>

<site>
  <company>1001</company>   
  <name>STORE #2332</name>
  <streetAddress>123 City of New Orleans</streetAddress>    
  <city>New Orleans</city>  
  <status>A</status>
</site>

<site>
  <company>1002</company>   
  <name>STORE #2333</name>
  <streetAddress>123 Bla bla bla</streetAddress>
  <city>Somewhere</city>    
  <status>A</status>
</site>
</siteelement>
```

Question : How can I make my reader reads through all my xml document? What did I miss? What is incorrect?

**Any** help would be appreciated. Please notice I am completely new to Visual Basic (less than a week!) and if you think I can betterize my code...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this will throw an exception - you are calling `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` again (at the end of the inner loop), after the command has been disposed.  I don't know if there are other issues, but try removing that line and see if that helps (you probably should not be opening the connection inside the loop).  You should also look into the [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement to help with resource clean-up.

Comment: You are right, this was throwing an exception. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first iteration of your loop you are opening your `SqlConnection`, but never closing it. Then, on the next iteration of your loop, you are trying to open your `SqlConnection` again, which throws the following exception since the connection was already open:

`The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.`

I have made some minor changes to your code to demonstrate the proper way to handle a `SqlConnection` (or any other object that implements the `IDisposable` interface).

```vb
Dim xmlFile As String
Dim connectionString As String
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim reader As XmlReader
Dim sqlStatement As String

'Tag names inside xml document, will have to be inserted into table
Dim company As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim streetaddress As String
Dim city As String
Dim status As Char

connectionString = "this connection string works"
xmlFile = "MyXMLFile.xml"
reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, New XmlReaderSettings())
ds.ReadXml(reader)

Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(xmlFile)
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes(".//siteelement/site")
For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        company = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))
        name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)
        streetaddress = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)
        city = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3)
        status = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4)

        sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SITE] ([COMPANY], [NAME], [STREETADDRESS], [CITY], [STATUS]) VALUES (@COMPANY, @NAME, @STREETADDRESS, @CITY, @STATUS)"

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Using command As New SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY", company)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", name)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STREETADDRESS", streetaddress)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITY", city)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", status)
                Try
                    connection.Open()
                    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    Console.WriteLine(rowsAffected & " entries were inserted into Site table")
                    'Release the resources
                    command.Dispose()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                End Try
                'Execute the sql statement against the connection
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using
        End Using

    Next
Next
```

You'll notice that I wrapped your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in a funny-looking `Using` block rather than using the `Dim` keyword. The purpose of the `Using` block is to ensure that ALL of the resources are properly disposed of when the end of the `Using` block is reached.

So in my code sample, the `SQLConnection` object is completely destroyed and re-created on each iteration of the loop and therefore the `connection.Open()` statement is valid for every iteration.

Obviously destroying and re-creating a new `SqlConnection` on every iteration is not the most efficient method, but I didn't want to modify your code too much since you said you're still learning.

Alternatively, you could have simply added a line of code to close the connection such as `connection.Close()`, but I feel that this demonstrates better coding practice.

Comment: I am sorry. For some strange reason, I did put my connection.Close() after the second Next statement (just before the End Sub), but it did not show in there. It's too late for me to edit it, you did already. And yes, please modify it, the more I learn, the better I will become. Thank you for taking the time to do it, I greatly appreciate your gesture.